# How to estimate gas needed

Tags: ethers.js, gas-estimate

**For the context (can be skipped) :** I have some deposit accounts containing some ERC20 token but no ETH. I would like to send all this ERC20 to a main account. In order to do that, I need to send ETH to these deposit account (to pay for the gas fee for the ERC20 transfer). But I don't want to waste ETH (there may be hundred of account a month).

**So, my question is :** Is there a way to estimate the gas amount needed for a transaction without needing to have ETH in the account ?

**What I have already tried :** Using the ethers.js library I tried with the following command -> `let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signerNewAddress);let estimation = await contract.estimateGas.transfer(signerOwner.address, ethers.utils.parseUnits("100",decimalNumber);`
With *contractAddress* : the ERC20 address, *signerNewAddress* : a deposit account address and *signerOwner* : the account where I want to send the ERC20 token. Unfortunately, because the signerNew address doesn't have any ETH I get the following error : `Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. The `contract.estimateGas.transfer` works even if no ETH on the account. My error was that I didn't have enough ERC20 token at that address.